# Easiest way to modernize communication protocol in enterprise WCF application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, enterprise

In our enterprise desktop application we are actively using WCF since 2010-2011 and we are quite happy with it.
However we see that WCF became less and less popular, it is not supported in .NET Core, which is sooner or later will replace .NET Framework, so we started to think about replacement for WCF in our application.
We want to replace communication protocol, but we don't want to re-write all existing services. We have extensions to our product that are written by our partners, so all of them will need to re-write all their services, it will take huge amount of time. While we don't mind rewriting infrastructure of services registration, starting, calling and so on...
Main features of WCF that we use and that we definitely want to have in the future:
- sharing of contracts between client and server - we control both client side and server side of our app and they are both written in C#, so I think for us having a contracts is an advantage
- operation invokers: we use them to add logging for every WCF call, to wrap calls in transactions, to change culture of the thread and so on

Is there a way to write a kind of wrapper around existing services, data contracts and service contracts, to be able to call them in same way as now, but to use another modern communication protocol under-the-hood: gRPC, Web API, etc.?

Comment: What about a Restful Api to replace WCF Services?

Comment: Each of the things you miss can be achieved in different ways. Research each one separately, see duplicate for a starting point.

Comment: Web API is a new technology, while WCF is completed (wpf is also completed but is still widely used. Until xamarin forms for desktop will come). Take a look at comparison table to see which suits your needs best: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-and-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @JanMer we are going to continue using services approach, like in WCF. Rewriting application using REST API will take couple of years...

Comment: @CodeCaster I've added a remark to my question, why IpcServiceFramework is not a solution. Do you still think it is duplicated? I understand that I can somehow achieve what I'm asking, but that's why I'm asking it - to get some suggestions.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok, I will try to formulate another question that describes my question more precisely

Comment: @CodeCaster tried to re-think what exactly do I need :) Hope it is better now

Answer (score 1):

I have researched similar "wrap" around ideas for existing WCF services that I have which are running over basic HTTP bindings as good old SOAP web services.

It seems like there is no way to change the protocol to something more modern (e.g. gRPC or JSON based web APIs) without significant rewrite of the underlying codes. For example, although you can switch your WCF binding to WebHttpBinding and your operation/data contracts to make your services behave like more modern RESTful APIs, it would probably make more sense to just port the current codes over to ASP.Net MVC any way.

Another alternative I've looked into was to extend WCF by implementing custom bindings to change the underlying protocol. [WCF custom bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/custom-bindings) but I figured that the effort may end up being greater than the rewrite.